# Facebook Instant Games: Must Not Call Private APIs

Tags: svelte, facebook-instant-games

Upon uploading to Facebook Instant Games we got the error "Must Not Call Private APIs: Games must use the Instant Games SDK properly and should not call private methods directly."

We are using the same set of publicly documented functions found in the [Quickstart](https://github.com/fbsamples/fbinstant-samples/tree/main/examples/hello-world), and have greped the build output for offenders, revealing nothing. No documentation. No hits on the internet. AI has no idea.

Next steps?

Answer (score 0):

Through a long game of submitting chunks of code through FB servers for validation (binary search), the problem was a `parent.postMessage` call in the Svelte runtime function `add_iframe_resize_listener`.

I'll leave it as an exercise for reader to decide what to do about it. Hopefully this saves someone a day of their lives to go drink on a beach instead.